# GPG search-keys always returning Error searching keyserver: Certificate expired. How to resolve this?

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

I'm trying to verify a downloaded file using GnuPG in Windows 10. I had installed Gpg4win which installed GnuPG 2.3.4

*My problem:*

The following command (in powershell)

```
gpg --verbose --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --search-keys "libreoffice build team"
```

always returns

```
gpg: error searching keyserver: Certificate expired
gpg: keyserver search failed: Certificate expired
```

Tried the same in kleopatra, it shows blank.

Then went ahead and replaced hkps with hkp and it worked. However, as I understand, hkps is preferred as it is so between http and https.

Any help to get to the solution would be highly appreciated!

I tried setting dirmngr config to produce verbose output in a log file. Following text is from the log file:

```
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] listening on socket 'C:\\Users\\-----\\AppData\\Local\\gnupg\\S.dirmngr'
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] permanently loaded certificates: 96
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476]     runtime cached certificates: 0
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476]            trusted certificates: 96 (96,0,0,0)
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] handler for fd 1020 started
2022-03-29 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] resolve_dns_addr for 'keyserver.ubuntu.com': '162.213.33.9'
2022-03-29 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] resolve_dns_addr for 'keyserver.ubuntu.com': '162.213.33.8'
2022-03-29 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] detected interfaces: IPv4
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] certificate already cached
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] certificate cached
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] Note: non-critical certificate policy not allowed
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] certificate is good
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] certificate has expired
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] (expired at 2021-09-29 19:21:40)
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] Note: non-critical certificate policy not allowed
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] certificate is good
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] certificate has expired
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] (expired at 2021-09-30 14:01:15)
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] root certificate is good and trusted
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] target certificate is NOT valid
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] TLS handshake failed: Certificate expired <Dirmngr>
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] error connecting to 'https://162.213.33.9:443': Certificate expired
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] command 'KS_SEARCH' failed: Certificate expired
2022-03-28 14:01:01 dirmngr[13476] handler for fd 1020 terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but with gpg 2.3.7 on Windows 11. With the help of people at https://dev.gnupg.org/T6142, I found a solution. It involved deleting 'DST Root CA X3' certificates expiring at the end of September 2021, located in the 'Manage user certificates' Control Panel snap-in.

Comment: Ok. But something doesn't feel right: removing a trusted root CA to make an invalid certificate become valid.